# Cannot define property 'compilation' of undefined using Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using Webpack to bundle a node project. When I run 'webpack-dev-server --open' command, I get the following error

```
ui/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:373
    throw e;
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'compilation' of undefined
    at UglifyJsPlugin.apply (ui/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:328:20)
    at Compiler.apply (ui/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:375:16)
    at webpack (ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:32:19)
    at startDevServer (ui/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:367:16)
    at portfinder.getPort (ui/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:358:5)
    at ui/node_modules/portfinder/lib/portfinder.js:196:16
    at ui/node_modules/portfinder/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
    at replenish (ui/node_modules/portfinder/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1006:25)
    at iterateeCallback (ui/node_modules/portfinder/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:995:17)
    at ui/node_modules/portfinder/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
    at ui/node_modules/portfinder/lib/portfinder.js:157:16
    at Server.onListen (ui/node_modules/portfinder/lib/portfinder.js:43:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1304:10)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! order-lifecycle@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the order-lifecycle@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have this in my webpack.config.json

```
const libraryName = 'order-lifecycle-widget';
const outputFile = `${libraryName}.min.js`;


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        library: libraryName,
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: outputFile,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new uglifyJsPlugin(),
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

I have the index.html file in the same directory as the webpack.config.json and index.js file in /src directory. Not sure what is causing the issue. Could you please help